# JQuery: iterate and dynamically change attr for each link based on the current item id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

My JQuery code returns the same value to the link disregarding the current product id

The shopping cart page consist of [i] number of products, each product has its own productId. because the page iterates and it outputs the [i] number of products, I am not able to include the productId inside the wishlist iteration which is also [i] number of wishlists.

So I decided to go with JQuery and select the attributes to change the link for each product so users will be able to click and insert the product to their wishlists.

The final link for each product should be http://example.com/customer.do?addThisProductToWishList&productID=[i]&wishlistID=[i]

I have tried the code below but it keeps iterating and outputs a very long link and only keeps one productID stored to be populated to each product.

JQuery Code

```
$(".details").each(function() {
            var _href = $(".addThisProductToWishList").attr("href");
                $(".ProductID").each(function(){
                    var _theProductID = $(".ProductID").attr("data-id");
                     $(".addThisProductToWishList").attr("href", _href + '&productId=' + _theProductID + '&wishListID=');
            });
        });
```

[image: Please see this image which describes the final output]

**EDIT**

**HTML CODE**

```
    <input type="hidden" name="wishListID"/>
       <span class="wishListID" data-id="<js:text name="ProductID" />"></span>
        <ul class="dropdown-list">
                <js:iterate id="wishlists" collection="<%=wishListsCollection.getLists(new Integer(1))%>" >
                   <li class="dropdown-element">
                        <span data-id="<js:text name="wishList.wishListID"/>">
                        <js:text name="wishList.wishListName"/>
                         <js:a actionpath="/customer.do?action=addThisProductToWishList" name="product.productId"  class="addThisProductToWishList">
                            <app:msg key="product.add_to_wishlist" /> </js:a>
                                            </span>
                                    </js:iterate>
                                        </li>
                                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you aren't referring to current context that's why you are getting same value. Use `this` for current context. I hope below example will help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.details').each(function() {
    var pID = $(this).attr('data-product-id');
    var wID = $(this).attr('data-wish-id');
    $(this).find('a').attr('href', 'http://example.com/customer.do?addThisProductToWishList&productID=' + pID + '&wishlistID=' + wID);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="details" data-product-id="1" data-wish-id="a">
  <a href="#">Product1</a>
</div>

<div class="details" data-product-id="2" data-wish-id="b">
  <a href="#">Product2</a>
</div>

<div class="details" data-product-id="3" data-wish-id="c">
  <a href="#">Product3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @kalpesh Thanks for the answer. I tried your suggestion, but everytime i get undefined to both of the ID's any suggestion??

Comment: Can you post your relevant HTML code and your JS code?

Comment: I updated the question by adding the HTML code, the JS code is the same I posted earlier.

Comment: I have tried to make code as seen in browser console, but couldn't. Can you post code seen in browser console (Pure HTML not JSP). I want that one entire `div` which has `class = row`.